Consistency Strength of OCA?
I was wondering whether we know the consistency strength of the Open Colouring Axiom (or Todorčević's Axiom). It is a consequence of PFA, so clearly it is below a supercompact, but I cannot find anywhere any lower bound. Is there something known about it?

This page says "The full OCA is consistent with (but independent of) ZFC" but I don't know if consistency of certain large cardinals is assumed.

Thank you! Yes the Wiki page is unclear, if you are interested Noah Schweber answered my question and it's with no large cardinals

In fact, OCA has no consistency strength over ZFC, since you can force OCA over ZFC via a variant of the forcing for getting MA$_{\aleph_1}$. See Velickovic's article in the Judah/Woodin collection Set theory of the continuum (page 142).

Thank you Noah, perfect! That's a very nice result
